# Node Scripts: Chaining commands with watchify

Tags: node.js, browserify, watchify

I'm using npm scripts (see my npm file below) to watch files for changes with `watchify` and then compile and notify once compiled. However what happens is that the watchify task runs (this takes 40s when first run) then the `notify:js` task gets immediately called. I would like the `notify:js` to be called after watchify has finished compiling.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "exorcist": "^0.4.0",
    "osx-notifier": "^0.2.2",
    "watchify": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "watchify src/app.js -o build/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] -dv | npm run notify:js",
    "compile:js": "browserify -e src/app.js -d -o build/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] -v",
    "notify:js": "osx-notifier --title 'JavaScript Compiled' --message 'JavaScript compiled to build/bundle.js' --type pass"
  }
}
```

I've tried the following command variations.

```
watchify src/app.js -o build/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] \
-dv & npm run notify:js
```

The above command does the same as the `|` operator.

```
watchify src/app.js -o build/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] \
-dv && npm run notify:js
```

The above command does the same as the `&` operator.

I can't see any option in the [watchify documentation](https://github.com/substack/watchify) for what I am trying to achieve. Am I missing something here or is this not possible with the way I am trying to do this?

Comment: watchify runs in the background, so I think you can't use it to do what you want in a traightforward way. If you replace watchify by browserify, then the last variant of commands you have tried (with `&&`) should work; but you would loose the benefit of watchify recompiling the files on change. Otherwise, try to watch the change son bundle.js, and (re)start the notifier only when that happens...

Comment: Have you considered using something like [`gulp`](http://gulpjs.com/)?

Comment: @robertklep I've used `gulp` and `grunt` but I'm moving away from those tools in favour of this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this using [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) and [browserify-incremental](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-incremental).

This compiles JavaScript into a `bundle.js` file.

```
browserifyinc -e resources/assets/js/app.js -o public/assets/js/bundle.js --cachefile .browserify-cache.json && npm run notify:js
```

This is my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babelify": "^6.1.3",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "browserify-incremental": "^3.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.3.8"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run compile:js && npm run compile:sass",
    "watch": "npm run watch:js & npm run watch:sass",
    "notify:js": "osascript -e 'display notification \"JavaScript compiled to public/assets/js/bundle.js\" with title \"JavaScript Compiled\"'",
    "notify:sass": "osascript -e 'display notification \"CSS compiled to public/assets/js/app.js\" with title \"CSS Compiled\"'",
    "compile:js": "browserifyinc -e resources/assets/js/app.js -o public/assets/js/bundle.js --cachefile .browserify-cache.json && npm run notify:js",
    "compile:sass": "sass resources/assets/sass/app.scss:public/assets/css/app.css && npm run notify:sass",
    "watch:js": "nodemon --watch 'resources/assets/js' --exec 'npm run compile:js'",
    "watch:sass": "nodemon --watch 'resources/assets/sass' -e scss --exec 'npm run compile:sass'"
  }
}
```